# mysqli case issue select from inside case

Tags: php, mysql, case

hello this is my code can anyone suggest me where is the wrong bec i am getting erors

```
select m.verify 
CASE eore WHEN '1' THEN c.mobile from epmem m, empl c 
WHEN '2' THEN c.gender from epmem m, comp c 
ELSE NULL END, 
as 'expose' where (c.rid=m.mid) order by mid desc limit 50
```

the error is

```
 #1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 
'CASE eore WHEN '1' THEN c.mobile 
 from epmem m, empl c WHEN '2' THEN c.gender fro' Ã  la ligne 1
```

this is what i am trying to achive
i want to join one table with another table other table is dynamic and will be accourding to case value....

what i want is that join empl with epmem for case 1 and join comp with epmem when case 2 and also select related data as in code....

Comment: Comma after `m.verify` and `END` after `c.mobile`

Comment: You should (a) post the errors you are getting and (b) format your code so its more readable. You might be surprised to see the errors yourself once the code is properly formatted.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Every `CASE` statements has `END`

```
SELECT m.verify,m.mid,
CASE eore
WHEN '1' THEN c.mobile
WHEN '2' THEN d.gender
ELSE NULL END AS 'expose'
FROM epmem m 
INNER JOIN empl c ON c.rid = m.mid
INNER JOIN comp d ON d.rid = m.mid
ORDER BY m.mid DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Edit :

```
SELECT m.mid,m.email,m.eore,m.date,m.ipj,m.verify,
    CASE eore WHEN '1' THEN d.mobile else c.gender END as expose1,
    CASE eore WHEN '1' THEN d.profile else c.profile END as expose2,
    CASE eore WHEN '1' THEN d.veri else c.mobile END as expose3
FROM epmem m
JOIN empl c ON c.rid = m.mid
JOIN comp d ON d.rid = m.mid
ORDER BY m.mid DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: joining is always not with empl it depends on case value please look at the code in question case 1 hoin with empl and case 2 join with comp

Comment: Well, you have only one CASE in your question. @sonamSharma

Comment: i have two case each have a from statement inside

Comment: @sonamSharma if `empl.rid = epmem.mid` so epmem.mid = which column in table comp? Because we need to join these 3 tables.

Comment: the code works but when i add another field like WHEN '1' THEN c.mobile,c.profile then it shows error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91166/discussion-between-rubahmalam-and-sonam-sharma).